# SDK Testing Cross Platrform or Native

Tags: user-interface, testing, sdk

Helle folks,

There is an SDK which supports different platform(Android, iOS, Flutter etc.) and i want to test by integrating it to a test app. UI testing is essential but which platform which i should chose i am not sure. Is there any idea? If i close test app build with Flutter, there will be no need for Android and iOS UI tests separately. But with this method, I am concerned that I may encounter problems that I would not have faced if I had chosen to test Android and iOS separately.

I want to show opinions.